# Crossdomain sitemap.xml

Tags: seo, cross-domain, sitemap

I currently have an online application that allows users to create personal pages on multiple different domain names, including the main one.

User websites can look like this:

- john.mainappdoman.com - mainappdomain.com is the main domain name which users use to create their websites
- user.hosteddomain.com
- another.secondarydomain.com
- third.mydomain.com

Is it ok if I generate a single sitemap.xml that includes all user websites from all domain names ? Can the sitemap.xml be the same for all domain names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the following ways:

- A single Sitemap that includes URLs for multiple websites, including sites from different domains. For example, the Sitemap located at http://host1.example.com/sitemap.xml can include URLs for the following sites:

http://host1.example.com

http://host2.example.com

http://host1.example1.com

http://host1.example.ch

- Individual Sitemaps (one for each site) that all reside in a single location. For example:

http://host1.example.com/host1-example-sitemap.xml

http://host1.example.com/host2-example-sitemap.xml

http://host1.example.com/host1-example1-sitemap.xml

http://host1.example.com/host1-example-ch-sitemap.xml

More info is available [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/i4LCwsj5p5Y).

Answer (score 4):

**No.** You cannot put all the URLs of all your websites in a single `sitemap.xml` file. Each domain and sub-domain is viewed as a different website and as such each must have its own `sitemap.xml` file.

Last paragraph of the first section of http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

> Also, all URLs in a Sitemap must be from a single host, such as www.example.com **or** store.example.com. For further details, refer the Sitemap file location

*Emphasis mine. The **or** is an English language **or** which is exclusive: one or the other, not both.*

So clearly you cannot have a URL from `host1.example.com` and `host2.example.com` in the same `sitemap.xml`.

Further, as pointed out by hyip's answer, the `sitemap.xml` needs to be in the root directory of your website. See this answer: http://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html#faq_sitemap_location

> All URLs listed in the Sitemap must reside on the same host as the Sitemap. For instance, if the Sitemap is located at `http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml`, it can't include URLs from `http://subdomain.example.com`. If the Sitemap is located at `http://www.example.com/myfolder/sitemap.xml`, it can't include URLs from `http://www.example.com`.

You can break the cross domain location of the `sitemap.xml` file by using the [`robots.txt`](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt#google-supported-non-group-member-lines) to indicate where the `sitemap.xml` is. However, that does not mean you can create one `sitemap.xml` that includes URLs from all your websites.

```
sitemap: http://sitemaps.example.com/subdomain-sitemap.xml
```

Note that with a good CMS you should have no problems creating one `sitemap.xml` for each one of your website. And it probably will be easier because you certainly won't hit the 50,000 URLs per XML file limit, whereas, one single file possibly would...

Answer (score 2):

According to sitemap.org there is also allowed to map a multiple domains in a sitemap which is described in [sitemaps_cross_submits](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#sitemaps_cross_submits). I take the detail explanation here for your convenient.

To submit Sitemaps for multiple hosts from a single host, you need to "prove" ownership of the host(s) for which URLs are being submitted in a Sitemap.

Referring to this Here's an example. Let's say that you want to submit Sitemaps for 3 hosts:

```
www.host1.com with Sitemap file sitemap-host1.xml
www.host2.com with Sitemap file sitemap-host2.xml
www.host3.com with Sitemap file sitemap-host3.xml
```

Moreover, you want to place all three Sitemaps on a single host: www.sitemaphost.com. So the Sitemap URLs will be:

```
http://www.sitemaphost.com/sitemap-host1.xml
http://www.sitemaphost.com/sitemap-host2.xml
http://www.sitemaphost.com/sitemap-host3.xml
```

By default, this will result in a "cross submission" error since you are trying to submit URLs for www.host1.com through a Sitemap that is hosted on www.sitemaphost.com (and same for the other two hosts). One way to avoid the error is to prove that you own (i.e. have the authority to modify files) www.host1.com. You can do this by modifying the robots.txt file on www.host1.com to point to the Sitemap on www.sitemaphost.com.

In this example, the robots.txt file at http://www.host1.com/robots.txt would contain the line "Sitemap: http://www.sitemaphost.com/sitemap-host1.xml". By modifying the robots.txt file on www.host1.com and having it point to the Sitemap on www.sitemaphost.com, you have implicitly proven that you own www.host1.com. In other words, whoever controls the robots.txt file on www.host1.com trusts the Sitemap at http://www.sitemaphost.com/sitemap-host1.xml to contain URLs for www.host1.com. The same process can be repeated for the other two hosts.

Now you can submit the Sitemaps on www.sitemaphost.com.
When a particular host's robots.txt, say http://www.host1.com/robots.txt, points to a Sitemap or a Sitemap index on another host; it is expected that for each of the target Sitemaps, such as http://www.sitemaphost.com/sitemap-host1.xml, all the URLs belong to the host pointing to it. This is because, as noted earlier, a Sitemap is expected to have URLs from a single host only.